# Python の正規表現置換で、日本語テクストを取り扱いたい

Tags: python, 正規表現

お世話になります。

Adobe InDesign に「配置」するために、Windows 上の『一太郎』から出力した Shift JIS のテクストを、Python の正規表現置換で整形したい、と望んでいます。
実際には、文中のルビや上付き・下付き文字を判別するために一旦、HTML に export してから、その HTML タグを取りのぞく過程を経由しており、そこまでは暫定的に終了しました。

ですが、「`単語<RUBY>たんご</RUBY>`」のような自家製タグを逆転させるような作業、つまり「`たんご<TMP>単語</TMP>`」の置き換えに失敗します。

わたしが書いてみた置換文は、

```
l = re.sub(r".<RUBY>.*</RUBY>", "\2<TMP>\1</TMP>}", l)
```

です。ですが、これを実行すると、当該場所にはエスケープ・シーケンスが当て嵌められて戻ってきます。

このような問題を解消する方法はありますでしょうか？
あるいは置換文の正規表現の問題ではなく、文字コードなどに由来する問題でしょうか？

どうか御教示くださいませ。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: `単語<RUBY>たんご</RUBY>` のような文字列だけが書かれた行が何行にも続いているということでしょうか？　何かしら仮定が与えられないと、`<RUBY>`に対応する前半部分が「単語」なのか「語」なのか「」なのか分からないなと思いました。

Comment: 後方参照をするなら、パターン部で`()`を使用する必要があると思います。

Comment: 質問の内容に限れば、`re.sub(r"(.*?)<RUBY>(.*?)</RUBY>", r"\2<TMP>\1</TMP>}", l)` でできます。たぶんその後あらたな問題にぶつかるんじゃないかと思いますが。

Comment: 。回答ありがとうございます。
パターン部で () を使う必要があった、というのが、一番当てはまりました。

ですが、仰るとおりで、それだけでは片付きませんでした。私の場合、
> re.sub(r"(.?)<RUBY>(.?.?)</RUBY>", r"\2<TMP>\1</TMP>", l) 
としてみましたが、それだけではルビが3文字以上のケースとの混在を尽くすことができませんでした。

Comment: でも、おかげさまで、今回希望していた作業が困難であることが分かり、マニュアル作業でこなすべき状況が理解できました。

ありがとうございました。